# Add sale percentage to products on sale with a shortcode in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

My code below creates a **shortcode** that will print the sale percentage of **variable** and **simple** products if its on sale.

My problem with this code is that with **simple products only**, the sale percentage is showing as 100% OFF when the **product is not on sale**. *I.e. no sale price entered*

If I set a sale price, so setting the product to be on sale, the percentage shown is correct.

The **problem is isolated to simple products that are not on sale**. The sale percentage should not be being displayed at all.

```php
add_shortcode( 'sale-percentage', 'add_percentage_to_sale_badge' );
function add_percentage_to_sale_badge() {
   global $product;
   if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      $percentages = array(); // Get all variation prices
      $prices = $product->get_variation_prices(); // Loop through variation prices
      foreach ( $prices['price'] as $key => $price ) { // Only on sale variations
         if ( $prices['regular_price'][ $key ] !== $price ) {
            // Calculate and set in the array the percentage for each variation on sale
            $percentages[] = round( 100 - ( $prices['sale_price'][ $key ] / $prices['regular_price'][ $key ] * 100 ) );
         }
      }
      $percentage = $percentages ? max( $percentages ) . '% Off' : '';
   } else {
      $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
      $sale_price = (float) $product->get_sale_price();
      $percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ) ) . '% Off SIMPLE';
   }

   $percentage = $percentage ? esc_html__( '', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . $percentage : '';

   return $percentage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually already have the answer yourself in your question:

- "when the product is not on sale. I.e. no sale price entered.."

If this is not filled in, no calculations can be made with that number, Therefore you must add an if condition before you calculate the percentage.

So change

```php
$regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
$sale_price = (float) $product->get_sale_price();
$percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ) ) . '% Off SIMPLE';
```

To

```php
// Get regular price
$regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();

// Get sale price
$sale_price = (float) $product->get_sale_price();

// Condition, isset 
if ( isset ( $regular_price ) && isset ( $sale_price ) ) {
    $percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ) ) . '% Off SIMPLE';   
}
```

- [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) — Determine if a variable is declared and is different than NULL

---

Could also be used, or a combination of both

- [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) — Determine whether a variable is empty

Like

```php
// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $sale_price ) ) {
    // $percentage =...
}
```