# Add the percentage of sale next to "SALE" text in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add the percentage of sale next to "SALE" text in WooCommerce. I searched for this and I found many codes to implement this but all doesn't work for me.
I need to do that for simple product and variable product, can someone say how can I implement this to [my website](https://thebest-select.com/)?

Here are some related answers I tried on StackOverFlow :

- [Adding the discount percentage to variable products on sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230027/adding-the-discount-percentage-to-variable-products-on-sale)
- [Add the discounted percentage to variable product price range in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798284/add-the-discounted-percentage-to-variable-product-price-range-in-woocommerce)
- [Add sale percentage to products on sale with a shortcode in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590292/add-sale-percentage-to-products-on-sale-with-a-shortcode-in-woocommerce)

I also searched outside stackoverflow and didn't find the solution.

Comment: We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec dear Loic, I have mentioned three answers. I tried all of them and all are not working, I am afraid i include my code so it considered as a repetitive content.

Comment: This excuse does not hold water… Anyway, you should provide your own real code attempt that shows your effort in solving your problem, even if your code attempt doesn't work, that is the rule on StackOverFlow.